# Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-8, hp-pavilion

I uninstalled Ubuntu by deleting the drive allotted for it from Windows Disk Management, but I guess I didn't delete grub. I
ve tried several videos, but none of them worked for me.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \BCD (not \boot\BCD)

  Status: 0xc0000098
```

Now I get Ubuntu and Windows option when I press <kbd>F9</kbd> at starting, but choosing Windows will will give the above error message and choosing Ubuntu will take me to grub command window.

Comment: Can you boot Windows directly by selecting it in the boot menu of  UEFI settings? Please note this, in a way, is a loaded question. Each time I read people saying they installed going by "videos" I expect the worse. In your case specifically, have you changed something in UEFI, like enabling legacy/CSM?

Comment: Try the windows repair process by booting with a windows install media.

Comment: Thanks for the response all. I did rebuild the BCD file by entering command line. But I still have the grub bootloader along with windows boot loader (I am able to enter windows). How can I remove this grub completely?